# Equivalence of greatest-lower-bound and least-upper-bound

Tags: real-analysis

There's a theorem in my textbook that states the g.l.b of the real numbers is equivalent to the l.u.b of the real numbers.

I don't completely understand what this means and how one would prove it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $X \subset \mathbb R$ we may define $$Y = \{-x ; x \in X\}$$